# Error with a makefile

Tags: emacs, makefile

What can I do to fix this problem? I'm trying to make a make file that will compile guess.cpp and yesno.cpp to produce the files guess.o and yesno.o, and will link those two .o files to produce an executable program named guess. This is my makefile here:

```
guess: yesno.o guess.o
    g++ -o guess yesno.o guess.o
guess.o: yesno.h
yesno.o: yesno.h
```

The error I am getting it 
make: `` *** No rule to make target `yesno.h', needed by `yesno.o'.  Stop. ``

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong and what I can do to fix this.

Comment: You can supply the file `yesno.h`. But you probably also want `yesno.o` to depend on `yesno.c` and `guess.o` to depend on `guess.c`. Which you will also want to supply...

Answer (score 1):

The basic makefile rule is

```
target: dependencies
[tab] system command
```

You miss the `[tab] system command` part. Try this below. And [this](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) is simple tutorial about Makefile.

```
guess: yesno.o guess.o
    g++ -o guess yesno.o guess.o
guess.o: yesno.h guess.c
    g++ -c guess.c
yesno.o: yesno.h yesno.c
    g++ -c yesno.c
```